# WP_Options table in MySQL db is over 1.1GB - how can I reduce the size?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a news website and it's too slow.

I tried to deep more into it and find it that my database is 1.2GB. I have over 7000 articles.

Should I delete complete wp_options table? Not sure how to reduce it.

I tried to use wp-sweep but nothing is happening:

[image]
[image]

Not sure what to delete

Comment: Could you identify which tables are the largest?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's not programming related. You may want to post this question here instead: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can I see which row inside wp_option table is the largest?

Comment: You will break you website if you just delete wp_options table, because a lot of necessary configuration also saved there. Try this one: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-manage-and-delete-transients-in-wordpress/ Make a backup before any changes.

Comment: Randomly deleting tables is probably a **bad plan**. It's like "Hey, C:\Windows is taking up a ton of space, maybe I should delete that." If a table is big, look inside and see what's going on. `wp_options` has a pretty simple structure, so you should be able to identify if it's a handful of huge records, or if there's just a ton of junk in there.

Comment: `SELECT option_id, LENGTH(option_value) FROM wp_options` should give you some insight. The structure is [described here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options).

Comment: @tadman https://i.imgur.com/7JKoFlK.jpg all these plugins from the list are in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [this article](https://crunchify.com/what-are-transient-entries-in-wp-options-table-transient-buildup-information/) is of any help, it suggests deleting the cached "transient" data:

```
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_%';
```

> As with any major database operation, before you do this **make sure you have backups** and that you've **tested these backups work**.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I tried diferent queries for transient and this one was the only that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

optimize table wp_options; 
drastically reduced wp_option table size, no harm for the website. But make sure do your backup anyway.